# fatal error: Tokenizer.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, netbeans-8

I'm using netbeans 8.0.3 IDE to compile a c++ project. I have four files in the project. main.cpp, Tokenizer.cpp, Tokenizer.h and myheader.hpp. what I did is that I created a new application project using the netbeans IDE and then in the main method that it already created I copied the code into it, and then I created the Tokenizer.cpp Tokenizer.h and myheader.hpp files respectively and in turn copied the code into it. when I checked the directory for the project within the netbeans worksapce all of these files are physically present. however whenever I build the project using netbeans it's giving me this error:

```
fatal error: Tokenizer.h: No such file or directory
```

I can't figure out the reason for this error even though the Tokenizer.h file is present and whenever i control+click on it, the IDE is opening the file. anybody knows what might I be doing wrong? thank you.

Comment: If you have `#include <Tokenizer.h>` with `#include "Tokenizer.h"`.

Comment: what do you mean @JohnZwinck

Comment: Sorry I meant to say: If you have `#include <Tokenizer.h>` replace it with `#include "Tokenizer.h"`.